# How to reach multiplied rows values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem in reaching to newly created select option values

```
<tr class="multiplied">
  <select id="company" name="companies[]">
    <option value="0">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">Compan  </option>
    <option value="1">Another Company </option>
    <option value="1">Another Company 2 </option>
 </select>
</tr>
```

When I select ona company I am taking that value and writing into another input, besides I have a jquery code which clones it that works like when I press to a button it loads that code

```
$("tr.multiplied:first").clone().insertAfter("tr.multiplied:last");
```

Everything works fine, the problem is when I clone that table row I cant reach the newly created rows.

The thing that I want to do is; taking the latest created companies[] value and insert into the same input.

How can I reach that ?

Comment: `$("tr.multiplied")` doesn't work?

Comment: it works but when I multiply that tr I need to reach the latest created one's option value

Comment: `$("tr.multiplied:last")` should work then, it was in your question too. You need to be more clear about what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to make a lot of these THEN edit their values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the id when you need to clone row. if not, jquery will still select your first row.
like this:

```
var nextId = 0;
$("tr.multiplied:first").clone().attr('id', 'id'+(++nextId)).insertAfter("tr.multiplied:last");
```

Comment: Don't forget to increment `nextId`